# Do people actually add webpages to their home screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, web-app

Many web apps and even websites like to prompt users to add their page to their iPad's home screen. This is particularly useful for web apps since if the website is launched from the home screen, it will appear in full screen mode (without safari bar).

Is there data somewhere on whether the add to your home screen prompt actually works? Or how many people actually add web pages to their home screen?

Comment: If you could elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve, that might make for an easier question to answer. As stated, an answer of "yes" or "no" could be offered. We have a nice guide on [ask] to help guide you if you find that no answers arrive after a few days.

Answer (score 5):

Just looked at my Apache Server logs to see if there was a difference in the user agent string when a page is called by an Add to Home app vs directly from Safari.

And indeed there is a difference.

The web app is calling itself:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B350"

While straight up Mobile Safari identifies itself as:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350
>   Safari/8536.25

This feature is very simple to implement using Matteo Spinelli's "[Add To Home Screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen)" script.  You could deploy it on your site and the look at your server logs and see if anyone is actually using it.

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen